# Is my old Dell laptop's battery the cause of it's not working?

Tags: dell-inspiron

I've got an old Dell Inspiron 9200 laptop.  It is about 6 years old.  It no longer boots up.  I replaced the power adapter a while ago, and so that's not the issue.  I'm wondering if the problem may be the battery?  Could that be why I can't power it up?  If so, I've got to replace the battery, but I want to make certain that's the issue.  (I should replace the laptop, but I don't have the money, and am not likely to get it any time soon.)

Comment: Just take that battery out and use the power adaptor. Unlikely it's the cause but costs nothing to try

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I just took the battery out, as you suggested.  It looked like it started to come up, but then just stopped.  Now that the battery isn't it it, and assuming it doesn't start up at all, does that mean there's something else, more serious, wrong with it?

Comment: You know, that may be working after all.  My daughter wiggled the cable from the power adapter around, and it seems to be working at the moment.  The battery is probably shot, but if we're careful with the power adapter's cable, it may be usable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the advice in the link to see if you can recover the battery

http://batterypower.co/battery-advice/calibrate-your-laptop-battery